# How to write rules under URL redirect in IIS 10

Tags: iis

I want to write redirect rules in IIS 10. I googled it but could not found proper solution.

I have added some more scenarios.

1. `https://testing.app.com/apptest` should redirect to `https://testing.app.com/apptest/account/login`
2. `https://testing.app.com/apptest/` should redirect to `https://testing.app.com/apptest/account/login`
3. `https://test-apptest.testing.app.com/` should redirect to `https://test-apptest.testing.app.com/account/login`
4. `https://test-apptest.testing.app.com` should redirect to `https://test-apptest.testing.app.com/account/login`

Appreciated if someone can please help me with this.

What I tried so far is:

```
<rewrite>
            <rules>
            <rule name="Test1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="apptest/login"  />                    
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
            <rule name="login">
                    <match url="^apptest" />                    
                   <action type="Redirect" url="testing.app.com/apptest/login" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>                             
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

Comment: Write another rule for `apptest/login` which does nothing. Then order the two rules so that the nothing rule can break early. https://blog.lextudio.com/iis-url-rewrite-tip-break-free-adccdb4b9f2f

Comment: @LexLi, can you please provide solution for my question. I have updated the question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the rule below:

```
<rule name="test5" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="testing.app.com" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/apptest$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.google.com/" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
```

Comment: Still it is pointing to google.com even i type  `https://testing.app.com/apptest/login`. I followed exactly your answer but seems not working for second condition. Can you please help me.

Comment: You only need to add a $ to the pattern in the second condition. `<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/apptest$" />`

Comment: I have added some more scenarios, Can you please include those scenario as well in the answer. I will be grateful to you. Thank you

Comment: Hi Samwu, Hi can you please help me. When I type `https://test-google.com/` or `https://test-google.com` then it should redirect to `https://test-google.com/tt/pp`. I am trying this way: condition `{REQUEST_URI}` to `^((/test)?)/?$`. then redirect to `https://test-google.com/tt/pp`. But I am not getting into it. Please guide me where I am going wrong.